# Div's are stacking instead of extending downwards, and it's pushing my content in the first div up

Tags: html, css

I'm a first year student and just working on an assignment, when I make my divs they seem to be stacking on top of one another, i've tried a lot of different things and watched youtube video's but nothing seems to be working, hoping someone can help me.

```css
body{
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

h1{
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.75em;
}

a:visited{
  color:inherit;
}


.container{
  display: flex;
}
.container-main{
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.topBar{
  top: 0;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f2efea;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  z-index: 1;
}


.secondNavigation{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 80px;
  background-color: #556052;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.container-secondary {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  max-height: 800px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  background: url(../images/aboutUS2.svg) no-repeat;
  background-color: none;
  background-size: cover;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box-1{
  flex: 2;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.6;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.rudy{
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.rudyBio{
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  line-height: 2;
}

.box-2{
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;

}

.container-secondary1{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    max-height: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 450px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="topBar">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/house.png" alt="logo" class="logo"></a>
        <a href="index.html"><h1 class='homes4Pups'>Homes4Pups</h1></a>
          <h1 class="aboutUs">About Us</h1>
          <h1 class="locations">Locations</h1>
          <a href="contactus.html"><h1 class="contact">Contact</h1></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="secondNavigation">
      <div class="container">
          <h2 class = 'rehoming helpCentre'>Rehoming</h1>
          <h2 class = 'sponsor helpCentre'>Sponsor Us</h1>
          <h2 class = 'Volunteer helpCentre'>Volunteer</h1>
          <h2 class = 'Covid helpCentre'>Information on COVID</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="container-main">
    <div class="container-secondary">
        <div class="box-1">
          <h1 class='rudy'>Meet Rudy</h1>
          <p class='rudyBio'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box-2">
            <h3 class='darg'>To find out more about DARG press the button below</h3>
            <a href="http://darg.org.za/" target='_blank' class="myButton">DARG</a>
        </div>

    <div class="container-secondary1">
          <div class="container3-box1">
            <h3>news</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="container3-box2">
            <h3>image of dog</h3>
            <img src="images/alfie.svg" alt="fox-terrier" class="fox-terrier">
          </div>
          <div class="container3-box3">
            <h3>image of dog</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is coming with container-secondary and container-secondary1, when i put change the height of container-secondary1 instead of the page being made longer, container-secondary1 overlaps with container-secondary and pushes the content upward.

[image: example of the problem]

Comment: You got two comments in your css code `HTML` and `**CSS**` which seems weird. Where is the HTML?

Comment: @Domink I updated it, sorry this is my first time using Stack Overflow and I got a bit confused

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me, that you are missing a closing  tag on container-secondary. Or it they are nested, you miss to closing tag on container-main

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you so much, I found it now, i've been going through this for 2 hours trying to figure it out, changing the structure and everything didn't think it was the tags but i somehow as you said nested it and i moved the closing tag and it's working now. Thank you so so so much !